# Python dictionary increment

Tags: python, dictionary, increment

In Python it's annoying to have to check whether a key is in the dictionary first before incrementing it:

```
if key in my_dict:
  my_dict[key] += num
else:
  my_dict[key] = num
```

Is there a shorter substitute for the four lines above?

Comment: can you do this same thing for two values?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

An alternative is:

```
my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, 0) + num
```

Comment: can you do it for multiple values? i mean increment more than one value

Comment: Without a loop? As `dict` doesn't provide a way to access multiple elements in a single expression I don't see how.

Comment: With a loop just like the OP writes in his question, but incrementing two values per key not one

Comment: I think you should ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 33):

You have quite a few options. I like using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter()
>>> d[12] += 3
>>> d
Counter({12: 3})
```

Or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)  # int() == 0, so the default value for each key is 0
>>> d[12] += 3
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7ff2fe7d37d0>, {12: 3})
```

Comment: For `lambda: 0`, you can just say, `int`.

Comment: @hughdbrown: Thanks, I never knew that.

Comment: @hughdbrown without your comment I would never have understood what a defaultdict was doing. Thank you.

Comment: It's a pity that the docs don't mention that `Counter` also supports the default 0 functionality. I have been using Nicola's solution until now, but it's much nicer without it.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is called a defaultdict

See http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 8):

transform:

```
if key in my_dict:
  my_dict[key] += num
else:
  my_dict[key] = num
```

into the following using [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
my_dict[key] = my_dict.setdefault(key, 0) + num
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also a little bit different `setdefault` way:

```
my_dict.setdefault(key, 0)
my_dict[key] += num
```

Which may have some advantages if combined with other logic.

Answer (score 1):

Any one of `.get` or `.setdefault` can be used:

`.get()` give default value passed in the function if there is no valid key

```
my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, 0) + num
```

`.setdefault ()` create a key with default value passed

```
my_dict[key] = my_dict.setdefault(key, 0) + num
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to **shorten** the condition can be the following sample:

```
dict = {}
dict['1'] = 10
dict['1'] = dict.get('1', 0) + 1 if '1' in dict else 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: `dict` is the build-in name of dictionaries. The answer is functunally equivalent to the already accepted one with an unneccessary inline if function.